# Using functionality of one class in another

Tags: objective-c, ios, geonames

I'm trying to use [ILGeoNames](https://github.com/InfiniteLoopDK/ILGeoNames) classes in my project. But I have problem with understanding in which way I can use this classes for my purpose. There is "simple project" in this framework. From it I want only one thing: country time zone (I already have county name). Because there are many method, variables and others staffs I can't understand what exactly I need to use. Please, help me solve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a bunch of classes and you want to make use of a certain class's methods or properties, then you have to #import name_of_class_you_want_to_utilize; at the start of your file and then make your calls. Class methods can be called directly, whereas instance methods require you to create an instance of the class to access them.